# Como puedo realizar un insert dentro un if

Tags: mysql

Hola amigos tengo este código en **mysql** 
mis 2 variables
proveedor...esta variable viene de un **stored producre** y todo bien
Acumulado_1...esta variable es la que declaro para compararla.
Lo que yo quiero que me haga el `if` es que si `Acumulado_1` viene `null` pues que me haga el `insert`.
saludos

```
SET Acumulado_1 = (SELECT Idproveedor FROM acumuladocomisiones 
                   WHERE Idproveedor =proveedor);
ELSEIF (Acumulado_1 is null) THEN
UPDATE acumuladocomisiones SET MontoAcumulado=Total_Prove
WHERE Idproveedor=proveedor;
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu codigo va bien, prueba con esto:

```sql
SET Acumulado_1 = (SELECT Idproveedor FROM acumuladocomisiones 
                   WHERE Idproveedor =proveedor);
IF (Acumulado_1 is null) THEN
     --INSERT----
ELSEIF
     UPDATE acumuladocomisiones SET MontoAcumulado=Total_Prove
     WHERE Idproveedor=proveedor;
ENDIF
```

Comment: Hola amigo gracias me funciono

Comment: Que bueno escuchar esto, si la respuesta es valida marcala como correcta para ayudar a otros.